# Concatenate two ranges without looping

Tags: vba, excel

I want to concatenate two ranges into one WIHTOUT using a loop.

Below is the code. The lines with comment's is basically the solution I want to avoid.

```
With ws_AUoM

    lCountEntriesInAUoMFile = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("O2:O" & lCountEntriesInAUoMFile).Value = .Range("B2:B" & lCountEntriesInAUoMFile).Value & .Range("F2:F" & lCountEntriesInAUoMFile).Value

'    For lLoopCounterAUoM = 2 To lCountEntriesInAUoMFile
'
'        .Cells(lLoopCounterAUoM, "O").Value = .Cells(lLoopCounterAUoM, "B").Value & .Cells(lLoopCounterAUoM, "F").Value
'
'    Next lLoopCounterAUoM


End With
```

This line:

```
.Range("O2:O" & lCountEntriesInAUoMFile).Value = .Range("B2:B" & lCountEntriesInAUoMFile).Value & .Range("F2:F" & lCountEntriesInAUoMFile).Value
```

returns the error "Type Mismatch". I have double checked the sizes and location of each range. Yet it does not work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Dim r As Long    

With ws_AUoM

    r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("O2:O" & r).Value = .Evaluate("B2:B" & r & " & F2:F" & r)

End With
```

`Evaluate` knows you're giving it an array formula, and will return the resulting array, which you can assign directly to the sheet.